# writing csv in vbscript with multiline fields

Tags: csv, vbscript, multiline

I have been wrestling with this problem with past 4 hours and to be honest really exhausted... I am trying to write a CSV file through vbscript with multi lines in few of the fields... thought it would be easy peasy ... not so ...My original code is

```
summary = "This is my brief summary"
description = "Hello" & vbCrLf & "Today, I am going to describe my issue."
reference_id = "0000102203"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set csv = fso.CreateTextFile(download_file_name,True)

csv.WriteLine summary & "," description & "," & "Consulting" & "," & reference_id 
csv.close
set csv = Nothing
```

All I am trying to do is create a csv, and when I use excel to open the file would show up as

```
This is my brief summary| Hello                                   |Consulting| 0000102203    
                        | Today, I am going to describe my issue. |
```

And what I am getting with numerous tries of replacing vbCrLf with vbCr,vbLf, chr(10), chr(13), "\n", "\n", "\r","\r" and heaps more

```
This is my brief summary| Hello
Today, I am going to describe my issue. |Consulting|  0000102203
```

Is there anyway I can actually solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OKay, after 4 hours of literally banging my head on the keyboard, I finally figure out how to solve the problem. So if anyone is interested ... Just changed this part of the code

```
description = "Hello" & vbCrLf & "Today, I am going to describe my issue."    
csv.WriteLine summary & "," description & "," & "Consulting" & "," & reference_id
```

to

```
desc1 = "Hello" 
desc2 = "Today, I am going to describe my issue."
csv.WriteLine summary & ",""" desc1 & vbCrLf & desc2 & """," & "Consulting" & "," & reference_id
```

Ta Da ... worked like a charm ...

Answer (score 1):

There is no actual standard. This RFC came well after CSVs were invented. So you can do what you want, but you'll also need code to read your own standard as other tools won't. Implement CR as a special character (code 222 has historical meaning for me - SurveyCraft) and replace with CR after importing.

From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180 (also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

> 2. Definition of the CSV Format
>
> While there are various specifications and implementations for the
> CSV format (for ex. [4], [5], [6] and [7]), there is no formal
> specification in existence, which allows for a wide variety of
> interpretations of CSV files.  This section documents the format that
> seems to be followed by most implementations:
>
> 1. Each record is located on a separate line, delimited by a line
>    break (CRLF).  For example:
>
>    ```
>       aaa,bbb,ccc CRLF
>       zzz,yyy,xxx CRLF
>    ```
> 2. The last record in the file may or may not have an ending line
>    break.  For example:
>
>    ```
>       aaa,bbb,ccc CRLF
>       zzz,yyy,xxx
>    ```